# Rmove javaScript function from response API

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How to remove this function `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push;` from response from API as string.

I used:

```
contnt.Replace("\\(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push\\", "");
```

Which is not working.

Also:

```
contnt = Regex.Replace(contnt,"\\\\(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push;\\\\","");
```

Which is not working either.

How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't need to escape any characters

```
contnt = contnt.Replace("(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push;", "");
```

Comment: are your sure that's the EXACT string, with the exact same whitespace, etc?  Are there any hidden chars?

Comment: the EXACT from api after create breakpoint >'(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); '>and my cod like EXACTLY but not work again